# Insert text instead of icon in an indicator application

Tags: indicator

I want to develop an indicator app using mono c#. I want to display text instead of icons in the indicator, how can I do it ?

Comment: Try asking this on http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: App indicators are a ubuntu specific API. You wont get any help for it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You will need c# bindings to libappindicator. You will probably need to generate these yourself using a tool like [bindinator](https://github.com/andreiagaita/bindinator) (meebey used this to generate the c# messagemenu bindings)

The help for the api is [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/c/appindicator/libappindicator-app-indicator.html)

I have not used it myself but it looks like you would call the constructor

```
void (* new_label)
```

to create an indicator with a label but no icon.

Answer (score 1):

The `"label"` property

```
  "label"                    gchar*                : Read / Write
```

A label that can be shown next to the string in the application indicator. **The label will not be shown unless there is an icon as well**. The label is useful for numerical and other frequently updated information. In general, it shouldn't be shown unless a user requests it as it can take up a significant amount of space on the user's panel. This may not be shown in all visualizations.

[Source of Text above](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/c/appindicator/libappindicator-app-indicator.html#AppIndicator--label)

Answer (score 1):

If you use python, you can use it like this:

```
        self.ind = appindicator.Indicator("new-task-indicator",
                                      "indicator-messages",
                                      appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
        self.ind.set_label("MY AWESOME TEXT")
```